# JPA Character mappings

Tags: java, database, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am fairly new to JPA and trying to get a basic entity setup.

I understand that table attributes are mapped to java types, such as varchar being mapped to a String.

In my table I have a column code which is a `char(2)`, and stores a two letter code.

How would I use this within the entity? I tried using a String, but it seems that this isn't the correct mapping to use.

Comment: What is JPA telling you when you map it to a string?

Comment: As far as I remember, hibernate doesn't really like char columns of more than 1 character. I know that this is not ideal, but can you change that column to be a varchar?

Comment: Looking over it again, I realised I had not added the Entity to the persistent.xml file. Once I did this, it worked correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String is the correct type:

```
@Column(length=2)
private String code;
```